# netplan is attempting to restart NetworkManager when renderer is networkd

Tags: networking, 20.04, raspberrypi, netplan

I'm familiar with the old-style interfaces config, but not netplan.  This is ubuntu server 20.04 LTS on a raspberry pi 4.

I'm trying to configure a static IP address, so I'm following along with online examples and I stupidly tried to use NetworkManager as the renderer (because I copied/pasted).  `sudo netplan try` correctly told me: `Failed to start NetworkManager.service: Unit NetworkManager.service not found`.  Silly me.

So I go back to `/etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml` and change the renderer to networkd.  And then I run `sudo netplan try` and once again get: `Failed to start NetworkManager.service: Unit NetworkManager.service not found`. Wat?

Check this out:

```
$ ls /etc/netplan/
total 12K
drwxr-xr-x  2 root root 4.0K Jan 24 20:33 ./
drwxr-xr-x 93 root root 4.0K Jan 24 19:31 ../
-rw-r--r--  1 root root  226 Jan 24 20:31 01-network-manager-all.yaml

$ cat /etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0:
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
      - 10.11.12.15/24
      nameservers:
        addresses:
        - 8.8.8.8
        - 8.8.4.4
      gateway4: 10.11.12.1

$ sudo netplan try
Warning: Stopping systemd-networkd.service, but it can still be activated by:
  systemd-networkd.socket
Failed to start NetworkManager.service: Unit NetworkManager.service not found.

An error occurred: Command '['systemctl', 'start', 'NetworkManager.service']' returned non-zero exit status 5.

Reverting.
Warning: Stopping systemd-networkd.service, but it can still be activated by:
  systemd-networkd.socket
Failed to start NetworkManager.service: Unit NetworkManager.service not found.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/try_command.py", line 83, in command_try
    NetplanApply.command_apply(run_generate=True, sync=True, exit_on_error=False)
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/commands/apply.py", line 181, in command_apply
    utils.systemctl_network_manager('start', sync=sync)
  File "/usr/share/netplan/netplan/cli/utils.py", line 72, in systemctl_network_manager
    subprocess.check_call(command)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/subprocess.py", line 364, in check_call
    raise CalledProcessError(retcode, cmd)
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['systemctl', 'start', 'NetworkManager.service']' returned non-zero exit status 5.
```

Why on earth is netplan still trying to restart NetworkManager when I've changed the renderer to networkd?

Answer (score 5):

Had the same problem, realised that apparently it's not enough to simply edit the yaml-file, you also have to run:

```
sudo netplan generate && sudo netplan try
```

Hopefully that'll work for you as well!